# In the crysral report I have to convert date in the date part format

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

In the crystals I have to convert the date into date Part as below format.

If date is 1) 23/09/2015 the convert in the format like Sept-2015

2) 21/3/2015- mar-2015

3) 19/2/2015 feb-2015

check it also possible in Sql server.

Comment: Can you show where are you struck?

Comment: actually user will enter date in this format like 23/09/2015. But the value save in the database in format like sept-2015

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Report Design, Right Click on date field->select Format field. Now you can see more date formats including your required format